# viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is crashing on "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"

Tags: uicollectionview

sometimes im getting this "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array" error from viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind. it only happens sometimes, usually the collection loads normally and everything runs smoothly. i wonder what array is empty ?  the registered cells ?
(i tried registering them by code or from the interface builder and still no change)

im guessing that sometimes this method is being called too early in the loading of the collection and is lacking some data that hasn't yet been loaded.

can someone point me to any direction ?

my implementation is pretty straight forward: 
(and i used the right reuse identifiers on the views)

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath{
UICollectionReusableView *theView;

if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
{
    theView = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
} else {
    theView = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"footer" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
}

return theView;}
```

Comment: this still happens, anyone has any idea why ?

Comment: i hade the same strange probem - only on ios7 - fixed it by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974460/dequeuereusablesupplementaryviewofkind-crash-on-ios-7-1-index-0-beyond-bounds

and did the section insets via delegate

Answer (score 1):

After long playing around with this crash I found that:

- it is crashing, if you are loading your collection view from Nib having set in Nib file non-zero Section Header size in its flow layout.
- it is not crashing, if you set in your Nib file zero size of section header in flow layout, and then set it in viewDidLoad appropriately:

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeaderView" bundle:nil]
          forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
          withReuseIdentifier:sHeaderViewIdentifier];

      [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:sCellIdentifier];

      UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
      layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, 50.f);
      [layout invalidateLayout];
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

I still don't know why this is sometimes crashing but it seems that if i wrap the this code with a try-catch block and allocating a view instead of dequeueing one, then the collection will continue to load just fine..

```
if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
   theView = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
}
```

turns into :

```
if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
{
    @try {
        theView = [theCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:theIndexPath];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        theView = [[UICollectionReusableView alloc] init];
    }
    @finally {
        return theView;
    }

}
```

i know its not a good idea to allocate a UICollectionReusableView but its a quik fix for now or until i find the real problem.

Comment: With try/catch it also crashes because collectionView expects header to be retrieved only by dequeue... and without alternatives.